# How to assert on a number which is comma separated in cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

While writing tests on an application I have came across a problem.

I need to fetch a number inside a span from the DOM and then assert if the number is between a specific range.
I can do it by using

```js
cy.get('#my_selector').invoke('text').should('be.gt',lower_bound).and('be.lt',upper_bound)
```

But the issue is the number is comma separated like 5,000.  and I'm getting an error as `"expected '5,000' to be a number or a date"`

Is there any simple short way to convert it into pure numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the javascript `replace` method to remove the comma and then add a `+` to convert it into a number, like:

```js
cy.get('#my_selector')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((num) => {
    cy.wrap(+num.replace(/,/g, ''))
      .should('be.gt', lower_bound)
      .and('be.lt', upper_bound)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks. Fantastic. This method works well.  I'm still new to javascript and Cypress

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.replaceAll()` to remove the "," then `parseInt()`

```js
cy.get('#my_selector')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(str => parseInt(str.replaceAll(',', '')))
  .should('be.within', lower_bound, upper_bound)
```